# How to resolve : java.io.IOException: jsse.alias_no_key_entry

Tags: ssl, tomcat, https

I have a Debian virtual machine with Tomcat installed. I would like to install an SSL certificate so that my website is in Https.

I received the following certificate files with my VM:

```
my-domain.cer  my-domain.chain.crt.pem  my-domain.crt.pem
my-domain.csr  my-domain.key  my-domain.ch.p7c
```

I created a keystore with the following command :

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias tomcat -keystore keystore.jks -file my-domain.cer
```

Then, I modified the file `conf/server.xml` file with the following code:

```
<Connector acceptCount="100" bindOnInit="false" connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false"
        maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
        keyAlias="tomcat" keystoreFile="/usr/local/tomcat/ssl/keystore.jks" keystorePass="PASSWORD" keystoreType="JKS"
        port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https" secure="true"
        sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3" SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false"/>
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error when starting tomcat :

```
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:983)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:535)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:1055)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:585)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:608)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:306)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:491)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jsse.alias_no_key_entry
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:99)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:224)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1103)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1116)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:557)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:980)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: jsse.alias_no_key_entry
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:330)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLUtil.getKeyManagers(OpenSSLUtil.java:104)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:239)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:97)
        ... 20 more
```

I do not understand where it can come from. Because my alias is however the good one ...

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 8):

In my case, the cause of this issue was that the SSL key alias present in the application was not same as the alias passed while creating the certificate.

`keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -alias dummyApp -keystore dummy-app.p12 -storepass password -validity 3650 -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=dummy-app, OU=Enterprise, O=Test, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=US" -storetype pkcs12`

To fix, this I had to correct the value of the `server.ssl.key-alias` property. As per the above SSL generation example, its value should be `dummyApp`.

Comment: For me too. I just used the command "keytool -list -v -keystore certificate.pfx" (windows) to discover the alias name and fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just had this issue, only with .p7b.
This error means your **keystore doesn't contain the original private key**.

Please make sure your **private key** (.csr) is **in the same keystore** with the .p7b chain.

I followed these steps:

**1.** Generated a key with a keystore:

> keytool -genkey -alias [alias_name] -keyalg RSA -keystore
>   [enter_keystore_name] -keysize 2048

This command creates not only a key entry, but also a **private key** in the keystore. That's why it's important to import the .p7b into the same keystore.

**2.** Generated a CSR from this entry:

> keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -alias [alias_name] -file
>   [csr_file_name] -keystore [keystore_name] -ext
>   san=dns:[FQDN_of_server]

**3.** Imported the received signed .p7b into **the same keystore** (I recommend you to download the .p7b into the same folder your .csr and keystore are in):

> keytool -import -alias [alias_name] -trustcacerts -file
>   [ssl_certificate.p7b] -keystore [keystore_name]

If everything's done right, your keystore will contain the generated private key **and** the received .p7b.

Comment: What if i just have a .crt file and a bundle, how do i got about installing the certificate then ?

Comment: truststore is for public keys and keystore is for private keys.  you can't import a public key into keystore.  To get my keystore working, I exported my certificate as a .jks file from my certificate provider, which exports the cert as a keystore, then I imported that keystore into my tomcat keystore like this:
`keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore mydomain.com.jks -destkeystore /root/.keystore`

Answer (score 2):

you need to import private key to keystore.

**Step1:** You need to download openSSL and then move to C:\OpenSSL-win64\bin
Next, type this command:

openssl pkcs12 -export -in C:\Keystore\certificate.crt -inkey C:\Keystore\name_key.key  -out C:\Keystore\server.p12 -name [name_alias]  -CAfile C:\Keystore\rootCA.crt -caname root

Note: if you use alias "tomcat" in server.xml

keyAlias="tomcat"

keystoreFile="C:\Keystore\server.jks"

keystorePass="your pass"

then [name_alias] = tomcat

**Step 2:** use cmd and move to C:\program files\java\jdk..\ bin  and type this command to convert p12 file to jks file:

keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass mypass -destkeystore C:\Keystore\server.jks -srckeystore C:\Keystore\server.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12

Resart your tomcat server

Answer (score 1):

## Execute the following command

```
#First step

jmendoza@jmendoza:~$ openssl genrsa -aes256 -out electoralsystem-cakey.pem 2048 -alias electoralsystem-cakey.pem

Enter pass phrase for electoralsystem.key: jmendoza

#Second step

jmendoza@jmendoza:~$ openssl req -new -x509 -sha256 -key electoralsystem-cakey.pem -days 365 -out electoralsystem-cacert.pem

jmendoza@jmendoza:~$ openssl x509 -in electoralsystem-cacert.pem -text

#Third step

jmendoza@jmendoza:~$ openssl pkcs12 -export -in electoralsystem-cacert.pem -inkey electoralsystem-cakey.pem -out electoralsystem-store.p12 -name "electoralsystem-store"

Enter Export Password: jmendoza

#Fourth step
jmendoza@jmendoza:~$ keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore electoralsystem-store.jks -deststorepass jmendoza -srckeystore electoralsystem-store.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass jmendoza -alias electoralsystem-store
```

## Configuration example with Springboot (application.properties)

```
server.port=8081
server.ssl.key-alias=electoralsystem-store
server.ssl.key-password=jmendoza
server.ssl.key-store=/home/jmendoza/IdeaProjects/dummy/config/electoralsystem-store.jks
server.ssl.key-store-provider=SUN
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQQfR.png)