# Spring Boot error on startup: java.io.IOException: jsse.alias_no_key_entry

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, tomcat, https

I have struggled with this for hours now and I don't know what else to try.

I have already looked into:[How to resolve : java.io.IOException: jsse.alias_no_key_entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56151272/how-to-resolve-java-io-ioexception-jsse-alias-no-key-entry)

But no answer solved my error.

My SSL certificate was issued by Let's Encrypt and I have received all of the data as text.

I converted the text into the files: devCertificate.crt, dev.key and dev.csr

Neither using OpenSSL nor keytool to import the .key and .crt into a keystore has solved my issue.