# SSL certificate in Spring Boot localhost

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, crt

I bought an SSL certificate on Namecheap and the certificate is for my website [www.centregracefoi.com](http://www.centregracefoi.com)
But the thing is that i want to test it on localhost with my Spring Boot app so that i can see if it works correctly before deploying it on the web.
When I try to use my trusted cert in my Spring Boot app. It shows me this error:

```
org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:297) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.graceetfoi.gf.GfApplication.main(GfApplication.java:26) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:278) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:197) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1038) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jsse.alias_no_key_entry
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:99) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:217) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1141) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:592) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1035) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: jsse.alias_no_key_entry
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:328) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:247) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

I searched solutions on Google but the tutorials I found, are always about self-signed certificate.
Can I test a trusted CA on localhost, or does it only fit the online website?
Thanks.

Comment: The more logical explanation is that you simply forgot to import something; a private key for example. Whether a certificate is signed or not has absolutely nothing to do with the host.

Comment: I downloaded a folder from namecheap and hear is what i saw inside:
www_centregracefoi_com.ca-bundle
www_centregracefoi_com.crt
www_centregracefoi_com.p7b
Where can i find the private key ?

Comment: ..this question pretty duplicates [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56151272/592355)...it has no accepted answer, but is still maybe help-/insightful.

Comment: Add your host to the /etc/hosts file with your public ip-adress. Don't forget to remove the entry again from the hosts-file when you are done testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain certificates don't work on localhost.
Try mkcert to generate a certificate for localhost. It crates a CA and installs it on the system trust store.

```
$ mkcert -install
Created a new local CA at "/home/amos/.local/share/mkcert" ?
The local CA is now installed in the system trust store! ⚡️
The local CA is now installed in the Firefox and/or Chrome/Chromium trust store (requires browser restart)! ?
```

```
$ sudo mkcert example.com '*.example.com' localhost 127.0.0.1 ::1
Using the local CA at "/home/amos/.local/share/mkcert" ✨

Created a new certificate valid for the following names ?
 - "example.com"
 - "*.example.com"
 - "localhost"
 - "127.0.0.1"
 - "::1"

The certificate is at "./example.com+4.pem" and the key at "./example.com+4-key.pem" ✅
```

More info: https://kifarunix.com/how-to-create-self-signed-ssl-certificate-with-mkcert-on-ubuntu-18-04/