# Cannot run Spring Boot application in Eclipse 2022-09 (Java 19.0.1)

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse

I am working on a school project and I cannot get the provided Spring Boot application code base to run. I have already emailed the professor and she was no help whatsoever. I am brand new to Spring Boot and am not well versed in Java. Any help would be appreciated.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.snhu</groupId>
    <artifactId>ssl-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ssl-server</name>
    <description>ssl-server skeleton for CS-305</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
                <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
                <version>7.3.2</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <goals>
                          <goal>check</goal>
                      </goals>
                  </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
## need to add server.  entries to enable HTTPS with SSL keystore, replace "????" with correct entries

server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-alias=selfsigned
server.ssl.key-store-password=GH1#er3%
server.ssl.key-store=keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
```

SslServerApplication.java

```
package com.snhu.sslserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SslServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SslServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Eclipse error

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.4.RELEASE)

2022-12-06 12:02:26.521  INFO 6012 --- [           main] com.snhu.sslserver.SslServerApplication  : Starting SslServerApplication on DESKTOP-TNRCNL8 with PID 6012 (started by legol in C:\Users\legol\Documents\College\CS305\Module 7 Workspace\CS 305 Project Two Code Base.zip_expanded\ssl-server_student)
2022-12-06 12:02:26.523  INFO 6012 --- [           main] com.snhu.sslserver.SslServerApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-12-06 12:02:28.406  INFO 6012 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8443 (https)
2022-12-06 12:02:28.414  INFO 6012 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-12-06 12:02:28.414  INFO 6012 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.30]
2022-12-06 12:02:28.489  INFO 6012 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-12-06 12:02:28.489  INFO 6012 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1908 ms
2022-12-06 12:02:29.189  INFO 6012 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2022-12-06 12:02:30.520  INFO 6012 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-12-06 12:02:30.528  INFO 6012 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-12-06 12:02:30.531 ERROR 6012 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:297) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.snhu.sslserver.SslServerApplication.main(SslServerApplication.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:278) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:197) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1008) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jsse.alias_no_key_entry
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:99) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:217) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1141) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:586) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1005) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: jsse.alias_no_key_entry
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:328) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:247) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    ... 20 common frames omitted

2022-12-06 12:02:30.533  INFO 6012 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

Comment: "**FileNotFound**Exception: C:\Users\legol\Documents\College\CS305\Module 7 Workspace\CS 305 Project Two Code Base.zip_expanded\ssl-server_student\Userslegolkeystore.jks" Well, does the file exist or not? Spaces in the path are one possible error. Try renaming the directories.

Comment: Actually, looks like something wrong with this property `server.ssl.key-store=C:\Users\legol\keystore.jks`.  You can see it's getting squashed on the end of your working dir without any of the special characters.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. I changed the application.properties and moved the file to where it should be. I updated the error Eclipse outputs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56151272/how-to-resolve-java-io-ioexception-jsse-alias-no-key-entry

Comment: Thanks for the link PeterMmm. I took a screenshot of my selfsigned cert and ensured the alias's match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research and assistance from classmates I found out the version of Eclipse I was using was too new for the code base provided by the instructor to run properly. I installed a version of Eclipse from 2019 and it started right up. Thanks to all who commented to help.